# How to use T-SQL TIMER and CONVERSATION?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, timer

I'm currently working on a simple web project with SQL Server 2008 backend.
I need to process some informations on background(database-side).
For example, suppose you have a table which contains two cell, x an y.
Each cell will can contain only a limited range of admissible values(such as an enum).
After a fixed period of time, I want to reset the value of cell x from "Processing..." to "Done".
I thought of using a **timer**: after an interval of one hour, a stored procedure is invoked in response to the event generated by the timer.
Despite the apparent simplicity of problem, I'm unable to find complete examples/use-cases *without* unnecessary complexity.
The official Microsoft documentation does not contain useful examples.
Can someone show me a simple and complete(self-containing) example?

**EDIT:**

I would obtain simply this: the user could insert some data in the database;
I have already set a trigger on the table update event.

The new row must be processed, after a short interval of time - Not immediately, so I need a timer - for example by updating some cells(in backgroud, *without* user intervention).
I thought the simplest way to obtain this would be (asynchronous)triggers + queue/services + stored procedure called asynchronously: .
Unfortunately, I'm unable to find some sample of code really explanatory, so I do not even know the correct syntax to achieve my goal.

I need to perform more manipulation on the data.
for example: *immediately after the insertion*, the cell field1 holds the value **1**.
After *1 hour*, the value of field1 must be set to **10**.
After *another hour*, value of field1 will be set to **100**.
Everything must be done in the background, automatically.

A sample code below:

```
/*
sample table
*/

CREATE TABLE Test_Table (id INT, identifier INT)
GO

/* procedure SampleProcedure should be invoked three times: immediately after the insertion, after 1 hour, after 2 hour. So we need a timer */

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SampleProc]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @message_type SYSNAME -- DEFAULT message_type
    DECLARE @dialog uniqueidentifier
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        RECEIVE TOP(1) @message_type = message_type_name,     
                        @dialog = conversation_handle
            FROM dbo.SampleQueue
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
            BEGIN
                COMMIT TRANSACTION;
            END
        ELSE
            -- handle errors
            IF @message_type IN (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/Error'
        , N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/EndDialog')
            BEGIN
                END CONVERSATION @h;
            END
            ELSE IF @message_type = N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/ServiceBroker/DialogTimer'
            BEGIN

                -- pre-process data in updated table; Here I show a "simplest" way to retrieve the last row added

                DECLARE @field1Value INT;
                SELECT @field1Value = field1 FROM TestTable WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TestTable)

                /* 
                Here, if field1_value == 0, then field1_value = 1; if field1_value == 1, then field1_value = 10 (after 1 hour);
                Finally, if field1_value == 10, then field1_value = 100 (2 hours after insertion) 
                */
                IF ...
                BEGIN

                    UPDATE TestTable SET field1 = <1|10|100> WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM TestTable)
                    ...

                    /* Where - and how - should I set the timer? */

                    BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (@h) TIMEOUT = 60; -- wait for 60 secs(1 hour)
                END
            END
            COMMIT
END

CREATE QUEUE dbo.SampleQueue WITH STATUS=ON, ACTIVATION
(STATUS = ON, MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,
PROCEDURE_NAME = SampleProc, EXECUTE AS OWNER);

/* default message type, default contract */

-- Create Services

CREATE SERVICE SampleServiceInitiator
AUTHORIZATION dbo
ON QUEUE dbo.SampleQueue ([DEFAULT]);

CREATE SERVICE [SampleServiceTarget]
AUTHORIZATION dbo
ON QUEUE dbo.SampleQueue ([DEFAULT]);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.Trg_Test ON TestTable FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /* the CRITICAL section */

    DECLARE @Handle UNIQUEIDENTIFIER;
    BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @Handle
    FROM SERVICE [SampleServiceInitiator]
    TO SERVICE 'SampleCycleServiceTarget'
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;

    /* Where - and how - should I set the timer? */

    -- SEND ON CONVERSATION @Handle MESSAGE TYPE [DEFAULT];
    -- BEGIN CONVERSATION TIMER (@h) timeout = 1;

    ...

END
```

I know this is a relatively simple question, but I am not able to find useful resources.
Feel free to let me point out errors!:-)

Thanks

IT

Comment: When you say a "timer", are you referring to a SQL Server feature, the .NET `Timer` class, or just to the idea of a timer that generates events?

Comment: I refer to SQL Server timer / conversation / broker features... and so on :-)

Answer (score 0):

In sql server Time bound code executions can be handled in two ways

1) using <kbd>[WAITFOR](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx)</kbd>

2) Using <kbd>[Sql Server Agent Jobs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)</kbd>

For more details read the links provided. and select the one suits you best.